# UILabels cannot set Text with int

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

My work is to load the csv text "FLYING TO POINT" and concat integer 1 and hence display on UILabel.

When i  run the following methods using iphone 6, ios 9.2 . It only shows the alphabets

Would you please tell me what to do ?

the following is my work :

```
lblDConnectStatus = [self constructLabelT:  _labels[40] :
                     CGRectMake( 0 ,
                                (demoViewLeft.frame.size.height - imageMenu.size.height)*0.15 ,
                                demoViewLeft.frame.size.width * 0.9 ,
                                demoViewLeft.frame.size.height   )  :@"#fff" :12 :@"TitilliumText22L-Regular"];


//

[lblDConnectStatus setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[lblDConnectStatus setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter ];
[demoViewLeft addSubview:lblDConnectStatus ];


NSString *cString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1];


lblDConnectStatus.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %@", _labels[180] , cString    ];






- (UILabel *) constructLabelT:(NSString * )content : (CGRect) pageFrame   : (NSString * ) colorHex : (float) sizeX : (NSString * ) fontStyle
{
    UIFont * customFont = [UIFont fontWithName: fontStyle size:(sizeX*self.view.frame.size.width/375)]; //custom font
    UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame: pageFrame ] ;
    label.text = content;
    label.font = customFont;
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    label.clipsToBounds = YES;
    label.textColor = [self colorFromHexString:colorHex];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
    return label ;
}
```

And the method of getting String via csv :

```
- (NSMutableArray *) readCSV: (NSString *) flag
{
    NSString*  filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"novax_en" ofType:@"csv"];

    if([flag isEqualToString:@"de"]){
        filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"novax_de" ofType:@"csv"];
    }
    NSError *errorReading;

    NSLog(@"filePath   %@",filePath);
    NSString *fileString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&errorReading];

   // NSString* str =  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fileString encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding];

    if (!fileString) {
        NSLog(@"Reading error  %@",errorReading);
    }

    NSArray *linesArray= [fileString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    return [linesArray mutableCopy];
}
```

Comment: Check the width of label

Comment: I don't see a problem. So Leena may well be right. Just a sidnote not related to your core problem: You could use `[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@ %d", _labels[180] , i];` in one go and therefore get rid of `cString`.

Comment: I think you messed up the width of the label. There is no way an int number converted to NSString will not be visible in UILabel.

Comment: But I want to do this, how?

Comment: How can I check thw width of UILabel  ?

Comment: put breakpoints and go step by step, print the width frame, see if it is there or not!!!

Comment: What I have found is that, if i load the content in csv and seperated by enter, the phrases automatically enter and miss my integer. If I type it normally, everything seems ok

Comment: Please see my edit question.